# Day Night Mode in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

Currently, I am working on the article based application. It has day/night reading mode feature. Application background color should be in black for night mode, and Foreground component should be in white color. I have created the category for UIView, UILabel, UIButton and UITextView, But I don't know it's proper approach or not. Please suggest me something.

How to achieve/Implement Day/Night mode in an iOS application?

Comment: You can use this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use the appearance proxies rather than categories. Anything that subclasses `UIView` (so basically any UI) will expose this to you.

Simply set these your desired appearance and all elements will inherit this by default. Take the following example:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

All UIButtons would now have these attributes by default.

You could simply implement a check when your app launches for the time of day, then set the appearance of UI based on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you did it like this, for example: `UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.white`, it's good.
Just don't forget to set a UserDefaults key when the dark mode is enabled, so that when the app is relaunched it will keep the previous appearance. Also, you may want to set black for the navigation controller, tab bar and keyboard and white for the status bar elements and titles for the navigation controller and tab bar (in AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar behavior by making an appearance manager, which can be configured with different color schemes. And in it I have functions like:

`-(UIColor*) colorForLabelInHomeScreen;`

After that You will need a user default to keep Your current color scheme and a way to reload Your screens after the user changes color schemes( firing a notification, because its one to many relation is a good choice ).

One of the good sides of this approach is that it can be extended very easily with new color schemes.